# Grep with string and negative/positive numbers

Tags: grep

I am looking to `grep` for a string that could contain positive or negative numbers.

Basically, I have the following text in a file located at `/home/Me/test`

```
dcredit = -1
ucredit = 1
```

I am wanting to search this file for a string, then from the output of that string match for a numerical value.  This value could be a static value or a range (any negative number for example).

Here is the code. I am writing this in `Bash`. I has been a few years since I have written in `Bash`.  My goal is to use the output from the grep string and search for a numerical value.  Based on that result, print X elif print Y.  I am going to be doing this for multiple file locations so I only want to change the assigned variables for each block in the script.

```
SEARCHLOCAL="/home/Me/test" 
SEARCHTERM="dcredit = " 
COLUMN="3"       
NUMVAL="<0"

grep "$SEARCHTERM" "$SEARCHLOCAL" | awk '$"$COLUMN""$NUMVAL"' "$SEARCHLOCAL"
Output=$?
if [ $Output == "$NUMVAL" ]
then
Print X
elif
Print Y
fi
```

The printed results from this is the two lines that are contained in the file.

```
dcredit = -1
ucredit = 1
```

The example above, I am only looking for `decredit` and if it has a negative value. It can be any value that is less than 0.

I don't know why I am getting the dual line output when awk should only be searching from the output of `grep`, and `grep` is only looking for `dcredit`.

AG45.

Comment: Basically, I need to search for a string with either any negative or positive number.

Comment: Click `edit` under your question, then select your code with the mouse. Click the button marked `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar - near **Bold** and *Italic*. That way your code will look like code.